# How to remove image from kubernetes(GKE) - Container image "<name/name>:latest" already present on machine

Tags: kubernetes

I have a failing `public docker hub` container and if I `kubectl apply -f ...` with the same version, `:latest` in this case, I am getting:

```
Container image "<name/name>:latest" already present on machine
```

I don't see the image anywhere, in this case I am running on Google Kubernetes Engine - and it is not in the google `container registry`.

The solution or workaround, is of course to fix the code error in the docker container, and add to the version number and push again - then it all works and get pulled.

But is there no way to clear the image in Kubernetes, something like in docker `docker rmi <name/name>:latest`?

Answer (score 2):

I think use `latest` tag - not the best. But if it is necessary, [official](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images) workaround `imagePullPolicy=Always`.

Why this not best way? More info can find [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#container-images).